# Pastel Colors in Phone/Dialer

Tags: google-pixel-2, 9.0-pie

I've got a Pixel 2 running Android 9 (Pie). The other day the colors for the contacts on the Phone/Dialer Favorites screen switched to what I can only describe as 'pastel'. They don't match the contact colors in the Messages App (though the used to). Switching a contact color in the Messages App has no effect on the new pastel color for the contact in the Phone/Dialer.

I don't think I fatfingered anything to cause this but I'm not going to swear to it. When I noticed it I had just picked up the phone and unlocked it to make a call.

Color Inversion (Accessibility) is not enabled. Dark Mode is not enabled. Phone is totally stock.

What caused this and how do I revert it?

**Update 1**

Co-worker with a Pixel 2 that recently upgraded to Pie noticed the same thing. It's quite possible the change happened at the same time for both of us (not at time of upgrade but a few days after). Is this something Google did? Something about Material Theming with the new Material Design they rolled out, pulled and rolled out again? Also, I've restarted and done a power off, so I don't think this is a transient glitch.

**Update 2**

Co-worker's Messages app has gone Pastel, mine has not so far, despite force stopping the Contacts App, the Phone/Dialer and Messages and doing a restart and power off. Phone is 23.0.208561757, Contacts is 3.0.6.209518734, Messages is 3.4.048 (Yehu_RC26_xxhdpi.arm64-v8a.phone).

**Update 3**

Yet another co-worker (Pixel 2 / Pie) has the same symptoms as me (Pastel Colors for contacts in Phone/Dialer only). So it seems this is definitely something to do with some kind of rollout of something by Google.

Comment: This question has been asked before and should be recognised as a duplicate. See this [query](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=contact+color+is%3Aquestion) for some guidance. Some have answers, some do not.

Comment: @wbogacz Related maybe, but I don't think duplicate.

Comment: @wbogacz I've got no Emergency Messages, I haven't synced contacts since I activated the phone and It's a Google device with the Google Phone/Dialer App, not a Samsung device (which has a different Phone/Dialer, right?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went to Settings->Apps & notifications->Phone->Settings->Uninstall updates (three dots) and ended up with 20.1.197612390. Colors are back to normal. Will see how long they stay this way and if they change the next time the Phone app is updated.

**Update 1**

The phone app was updated and the pastel colors returned. Downgraded again to get rid of them. It looks like this intentional on the part of Google.